# Why am I getting 'URI has an authority component' error running Selenium server from Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

The goal is I want to run a series of htmlSuites. (Must remain html). I've only usually run from command line with the standard jar -jar and that works swell.

Now I wanted to do this in java so I could handle multiple htmlSuites etc. So I've added the server jar to my classpath, and am parsing the arguments to the main class through a String array, but I am getting the following:

```
HTML suite exception seen:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
```

I am using the following code (this is all just for mere testing currently):

```
    String[] arguments = {
            "-htmlSuite",
            "*firefox",
            "https://www.mysite.com",
            "\\Projects\\temp\\selenium_stuff\\MyFileUtils\\html\\Feedback\\Feedback-(EM)Suite.html",
            "\\Projects\\temp\\selenium_stuff\\MyFileUtils\\results\\Results.html" };
    try {
        org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.main(arguments);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have been trying multiple things with the locations, but with how I am now parsing it in, it is no longer throwing an exception for not finding the suite file.

Any help is appreciated,